# Torch: Input type and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

**Note:** I have already seen similar questions: [the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013109), [tell torch not to use GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266350), but the answers do not work for me.

I have installed PyTorch version `1.13.0+cu117` (the latest), and the code structure is as follows (an image classification task):

```
# os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""    # required?
device = torch.device("cpu")               # use CPU
...
train_set = DataLoader(
    torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(path, transform), **kwargs
)
...
model = myCNN().to(device)
optimizer = SGD(args)
loss = CrossEntropyLoss()

train()
```

I want to train on CPU.

For dataloader, in accordance to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563376/), I've set `pin_memory=True` and `non_blocking=pin_memory`. The error persists even on setting `pin_memory=False`.

The training loop has the following structure:

```
for epoch in n_epochs:
    model.train()
    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device, non_blocking=non_blocking), labels.to(device, non_blocking=non_blocking)
    Compute loss, back-propagate
```

---

The error traceback (on calling `train()`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 233, in <module>
    train()
  File "code.py", line 122, in train
    outputs = model(inputs)
  File "...\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "code.py", line 87, in forward
    output = self.network(input)
  File "...\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "...\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 204, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "...\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "...\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 463, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "...\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same or input should be a MKLDNN tensor and weight is a dense tensor
```

---

**Edit:** There was a comment regarding possible issues due to the model. The model is roughly:

```
class myCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...other args...):
        super().__init__()

        self.network = nn.Sequential(

        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size),

        ... similar convolutional layers ...

        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)

        )

    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.network(input)
        return output
```

---

Since I have transferred both model and data to the same device, what could be the reason of this error? How to correct it?

Comment: Can you please share your model definition as well. It seems like some layers of your model are initialised on GPU, which might give the error.

Comment: @AzhanMohammed done. It's a CNN classifier.

Comment: Try passing ```model.to("cpu")``` explicitly, cause the model definition here does not show any cuda initialisation of layers, which is a bit odd, as your error says that the weight tensors are of type cuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to incorrect usage of `summary` from [`torchinfo`](https://github.com/TylerYep/torchinfo). It does a forward pass (if input size is provided), and the device is (by default) selected on basis of `torch.cuda.is_available()`.

If `device` (as specified in the question) argument is given to `summary`, the training happens just fine.