# Iterate over Dataloader which is loaded on GPU (MPS)

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-dataloader

I'm working with PyTorch on M2 Max.

I'm trying to improve computing time with the help of GPU.

I have a working variant with GPU:

```
mnist_test_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

network.to(device="mps")
for X in mnist_test_loader:
   X = X.to(device="mps")
   prediction = network(X)
```

But the thing is that when iterating over Dataloader, at first X is loaded on CPU and it takes time to move it to GPU `X.to(device="mps")`

I've been reading documentation for a while and have found out that it's possible to load data on GPU in Dataloader when creating it. To do so I add 2 params: `pin_memory, pin_memory_device`.

```
mnist_test_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False,
                               pin_memory=True, pin_memory_device="mps")
```

And the idea is that I pass data from Dataloader on GPU directly into network, which is on GPU too without having to move it from CPU to GPU when iterating.

**But then the problem appears:**

```
for X in moist_test_loader:
   ...
```

I can't iterate over Dataloader on GPU. When I try to, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempted to set the storage of a tensor on device "cpu" to a storage on different device "mps:0".
This is no longer allowed; the devices must match.
```

Any ideas how to deal with it? Maybe there's another way to get data from Dataloader? Thanks for your time.

Comment: same problem here and the exact same code (but replace "mps" with "cuda:0") works fine on cuda GPUs

Comment: What pytorch version are you using? Your code works fine on pytorch 2.0.1
May it be an issue with the dataset?

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about this question too and here is what I found from all the looking around and experimenting I did.

TLDR: `pin_memory=True` and `pin_memory_device="mps"` don't actually transfer the data to the gpu. They transfer the data from the CPU to page-locked (pinned) memory which allows for faster transfer to the other device.

LONGER ANSWER: Since I have access to both an "mps" accelerated device and a "cuda" device I wanted to try on both, and on both (adjusting for cuda vs mps), using your code running `print(next(iter(mnist_test_loader)).device)` gave me `cpu` which made me confused cause I seemed to remember that `pin_memory` would transfer the data over to the other device. I further got a slightly different error than you with the "mps" device: `RuntimeError: Placeholder storage has not been allocated on MPS device!` which I believe stems from the same place as it was later on fixed by adding a `.to("mps")` for each data point.

I then checked the documentation again, and I realized that I had been misremembering what `pin_memory` does. It only transfers the pinned memory to the other device and not the data. Apparently there is a difference, I am not the best person to ask about this, someone who is a little more fluent in computer memory architecture and gpu computing could [help](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-dataloader-pin-memory-true-help-with-data-loading-speed/181306/1) out here. This confusion is not help by the statements made throughout the pytorch documentation of `"the data loader will copy Tensors into device pinned memory before returning them if pin_memory is set to true"` which on a fast scan of the page can be read as copying the tensors over.

On a more careful reading though it does say that it **only copies the pinned memory over and therefore allows for faster transferring**.

I then checked all my old code where I seemed to remember (same as you) sending my data to the GPU with `pin_memory` but I always did end up having to use `.to(device)` to send it to the GPU device.

I hope this answer is satisfactory enough, that you would still have to do `.to(device)` and that `pin_memory` wasn't actually copying the data over.

NOTE: `pin_memory_device` ends up just being a [placeholder for the different backends](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/attributeerror-dataloader-object-has-no-attribute-pin-memory-device/170129/2). `pin_memory` does give a bump in performance when transferring data over but it does take time to copy the pinned memory over, so it has some base computing cost, so [mileage may vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563376/pytorch-how-does-pin-memory-work-in-dataloader). Though in most cases if sending data on GPU its a good idea.